# About sending mail via SMTP

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I am sending mail via SMTP module and when I sent mail, receiver see my mail address on Heading part. But I want to be seen like "GORKIDEV" which I specified in the code. Could anyone help me ?

Codes:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import sys

message = MIMEMultipart()

message["From"] = "GORKIDEV"
message["To"] = "gorkemkayas@hotmail.com"
message["Subject"] = "About mail sending"

my_message = "Sending mail via SMTP module with Python"
text_message = MIMEText(my_message,"plain")
message.attach(text_message)

try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)

    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()

    mail.login("gorkemkayas435@gmail.com","*********")

    mail.sendmail(message["From"],message["To"],message.as_string())

    print("Message is sent successfully !")

    mail.close()

except:

    sys.stderr.write("An error occured.")
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETox8.png)

I want to change mail part to  "GORKIDEV" like as Google.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Not sure if this helps, but have you tried using the format "GORKIDEV <email here>" as From?

Comment: If you are talking about "" message["From"] = "GORKIDEV" "" part ,yes tried like that but not changed.

Comment: Yes, it is correctly and I solved with that. Thanks a lot :)